# Unable to execute python file in azure batch pool using task. Error: The specified command program is not found

Tags: azure, batch-processing, azure-batch

The goal is to execute python file stored in blob storage using azure batch job.

-- created azure account
-- created pool
-- created job
-- created task

Batchpool:

```
windowsserver
Target Dedicated Nodes: 2
VM Size: Standard A1_V2  1vCPU 2Gb Memory
StartTask: installs python by taking .exe files from storage account
```

**Task:**
using python file stored in blob storage, just simply printing "Hello World".

[image]

**Output:**  Gives an error *Message: The system cannot find the file specified.*

[image]

By logging remotely to a batch node I was able to confirm that the python was installed.

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

**Maybe the syntax in "Command Line" to execute python script is incorrect?**

**I am not sure how to supply Environment Variables.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run Python script inside a Azure Batch Pool Windows Node as a Start Task, Refer the steps in this [**Microsoft Blog**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/install-python-on-a-windows-node-using-a-start-task-with-azure/ba-p/2341854#:%7E:text=Required%20steps:%201%20Get%20the%20python%20release%20that,and%20the%20resource%20files%20to%20install%20the%20features.).

I downloaded **`Python 3.12`** from this **[website](https://www.python.org/downloads/)** and **uploaded** the ***downloaded exe package in my Storage account container*** like below:-

Created a batch pool with **`Windows Server 2019 datacenter`** *image with 3 Nodes and 1 Spot node*[ You can create it with 1 Node too].

In the start task selected the **exe package** from **storage account**:-

Make sure you **`check-mark Include SAS`** while uploading exe package from storage account to batch task:-

[image]

[image]

**My Task:-**

[image]

Command line **script** to **install Python 3.12**:-

```bash
cmd /c "python-3.12.0-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0"
```

Select **Pool autouser, Admin** in the **Elevation level.**

Save the Task, And the Task ran successfully on the Node:-

[image]

I Rdp'd into the Node and ***Python 3.12 was installed successfully:-***

[image]

Now, I added **another hello_world.py** in my **Storage account** with **Include SAS checkmark** and **ran** it inside the **Node**:-

*Added **`hello_world.py`** in the Batch Start task > Resource files:-*

[image]

***My Start Task:-***

**Command line:-**

```bash
cmd /c "python-3.12.0-amd64.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0"

cmd /c "python hello_world.py"
```

[image]

Start Task Ran successfully, ***Make sure you Reboot the Node everytime, Before you run the Start task.***

[image]

I RDP'd into the Node and the files were successfully present:-

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Now I got it. Thanks!!!