# How to add Application insights to Azure batch account

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-batch

Im following this document to add the insights to the batch account. [document](https://github.com/Azure/batch-insights)

Following are the steps followed to add the insights.
Step 1: installed the batch_insights.exe and added in application package as I dont want to add in on the go as described in steps.
Step 2: Added environment variables such as ApplicationInsights_instrumentation key and application Id.
Step 3: Updated start task -

```
%AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_batch_insights\batch-insights.exe /install /norestart && start /wait
```

Step 4: In [document](https://github.com/Azure/batch-insights#generic) it is specified to add some python script, do we need to add the step at all and if yes, I need to download the script and how to run after that, Could anyone explain this steps in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The repository you are referring to is old and Batch service resource manager api has been updated with new features now.

Refer this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/monitor-application-insights) to Monitor your Azure Batch service via Application Insights, It gives an example to Write logs to Application Insights via .Net framework.

***Install this package:-***

```bash
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer
```

Refer this [**Github sample**](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/CSharp/ArticleProjects/ApplicationInsights) for the same.

In **`ApplicationInsights.config`** file update the Application Insights Instrumentation key:-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
    <InstrumentationKey>InstrumentationKey=xxxxxxxxb8220f;IngestionEndpoint=https://australiacentral-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://australiacentral.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/</InstrumentationKey>
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector"/>
  </TelemetryInitializers>
  <TelemetryModules>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
      <ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
        <!-- 
        Requests to the following hostnames will not be modified by adding correlation headers. 
        This is only applicable if Profiler is installed via either StatusMonitor or Azure Extension.
        Add entries here to exclude additional hostnames.
        NOTE: this configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
        -->
        <Add>core.windows.net</Add>
        <Add>core.chinacloudapi.cn</Add>
        <Add>core.cloudapi.de</Add>
        <Add>core.usgovcloudapi.net</Add>
      </ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
      <!--
      Use the following syntax here to collect additional performance counters:
      
      <Counters>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Handle Count" ReportAs="Process handle count" />
        ...
      </Counters>
      
      PerformanceCounter must be either \CategoryName(InstanceName)\CounterName or \CategoryName\CounterName
      
      NOTE: performance counters configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
      
      The following placeholders are supported as InstanceName:
        ??APP_WIN32_PROC?? - instance name of the application process  for Win32 counters.
        ??APP_W3SVC_PROC?? - instance name of the application IIS worker process for IIS/ASP.NET counters.
        ??APP_CLR_PROC?? - instance name of the application CLR process for .NET counters.
      -->
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
  </TelemetryModules>
  <TelemetryProcessors>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
      <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
    </Add>
  </TelemetryProcessors>
  <TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel"/>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

Try to initialize the Application Insight code from the sample and run your application.

You can also implement a custom code in a python file using OpenTelemetry and then send custom logs to Application Insights.  By running that python file as a startup task.

Refer my [**SO answer1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76225763/where-to-see-logs-of-print-statements-used-in-python-azure-function/76227708#76227708) to use Opencensus library to send logs to application insights, And this [**SO answer2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77519272/unable-to-execute-python-file-in-azure-batch-pool-using-task-error-the-specifi/77521426#77521426) to run python script in Azure Batch service.